# Windows Powershell issue on windows 10 for Azure

Tags: azure

I have windows 10 and also have Windows PowerShell which I am accessing via using as administrator. I want to use Windows PowerShell for Azure administration currently the version is 5.1 ..I am facing issues first is I am unable to run Install-Module AzureRM as its giving me an error Get-**

> PackageProvider : Unable to download from URI
>   'https://az818661.vo.msecnd.net/providers/nuget-anycpu-2.8.5.127.exe.
>   [

**[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqIYs.jpg)

Comment: I recommend you to update to [Windows PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6#upgrading-existing-windows-powershell) and use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0) module, the `AzureRm` was deprecated, although it may be not related to the error, but it is possible to solve this error by the way.

Comment: I went on this link but it says PS 5.1 Installed

Comment: by the way should I use azure cloudshell and use az cmdlet ..what is the professional way to use cmdlet in azure.

Comment: Q1.But your screenshot shows `5.0`, have a try to uninstall it and install again? Or could you check with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`?  Q2.It depends on your requirement, if it is not necessary to run it locally, cloudshell is convenient.

Comment: @user342944 can you solve your issue by the post below?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `msi` installation as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/other-install?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

The resource of .msi file is located [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v6.13.1-November2018). Nav to this page -> scroll down to the bottom -> download the x64 or x86 .msi file as per your need.

[image]

Note that the `azureRM` module will not be supported in the future, it's recommended to install the latest azure powershell [Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-2.6.0#about-the-new-az-module) module.

Answer (score 0):

Install the PowerShell by msi from GitHub
[PowerShell Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell)

[image: PowerShell Github]